# Debugging android chrome over USB on laptop gives 404 page

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, android-debug, adb

I've set up my laptop (Windows Vista 32bit) and my Nexus 5 to talk to each other over USB so I can use the inspector on Chrome tabs on the phone on my laptop.

I went through the steps at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

The laptop can see the Nexus, and I can open/refresh/focus/close tabs remotely on the phone.

But when I click on the "inspect" link to launch the inspector I get a new window open with

> 404 Not Found The resource could not be found.

The URL of the window is

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@178678/devtools.html?&remoteFrontend=true&dockSide=undocked
```

Is there something else I need to install?  For clarity, inspector works fine for tabs on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

- please check if there is a mismatch between the chrome version on your laptop and the chrome running on android device. I suggest you try with latest chrome version [on your laptop, preferably with canary](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) build. canary can co-exist with your regular chrome.

  I just verified i was able to use the `inspect` with chrome canary and nexus 5.

  [image: chrome remote debug]
- check output for `"adb devices"` on cmd prompt to see if your device is listed, if you do not have `adb` installed , this could be a cause, please install adb and [follow legacy workflow as described in additional information](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#additional-information).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but I'd already tried different Chrome channels, and adb was installed.  I went back to this today though, and it's just spontaneously working now when it wasn't the other day.  I had tried rebooting both the laptop and the phone already, so I'm not sure what changed... :(

Comment: @codemonkey it could be that on reboot your chrome browser got updated or new update

Answer (score 1):

If your device is listed in `adb devices` then try inspecting it again with [chrome beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en) for Android.

Ideally it should work without any issues if your device is detected properly..

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your both mobiles and laptop google chrome browser make sure both are using the same version of browser.. the same issue occurs for me, so I solve that issue by using this trick, hope it will work for you.